# IntelliJ IDEA - Edit color scheme editor to ignore 'No candidates found for method call'

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, color-scheme

I have a project with methods that have the following error:
'No candidates found for method call'

Those methods are barely visible in IDE, is there a way to set the color to white for them?

[image]

I want to change the font color for `logger` and `execution` in a project, I want it to match variable name color.

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be changed under `Settings/Preferences (on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | Groovy | References | Unresolved Reference`:

[image]